# Google Calendar API Credentials for WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am having some trouble figuring out how I can let users set their API credentials to get read-only data from the Google Calendar API.

I have it set up to use OAuth to allow a fallback. It allows the user to click for an access key to copy over and save.

However, I am finding an issue when I try to make it so users can enter their own API settings.

I tried the same method I used for the fallback, but even if they enter those credentials in they would still need to authenticate it with an access key.

So I guess my question is how can I just include a simple API key to be saved and used to get the data?

I haven't been able to find very many resources or documentation on this so even pointing me in the right direction will be very helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT: 
So here is a link to the part of the Calendar API I need to use: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

And if you compare it to the top of the page of this API page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

You will see the delete specifies that it requires Authorization, but the List does not. All I need is the list but when I have tried to connect with it without any authorization it does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: is the calendar you're trying to access public? what error do you get? posting some code might help

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not public, the users will have to authenticate with Google and enter the access code on your plugin configuration. [Google Analytics for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/) does this, check its source.

I don't see the problem with having the users authenticating, but one alternative is to add support for service account, like the [Google Drive WP Media](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-drive-wp-media/) does. In this case users of your plugin will enter the service account email and upload the private key file (I'm not sure if the Drive WP plugin implements it in a secure way).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just updated my question with some more information too if it helps make it any more clear.